# OOM in maven during build

Tags: java, maven

I need some maven help. I have a project with a complex set of dependencies. Recently, when I try to build it I get the following:

```
[INFO] Total time: 39:41 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-26T16:14:11-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 100M/30643M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.visitor.PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.visitEnter(PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.graph.DefaultDependencyNode.accept(DefaultDependencyNode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.transformer.NearestVersionSelector.newFailure(NearestVersionSelector.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.transformer.NearestVersionSelector.backtrack(NearestVersionSelector.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.transformer.NearestVersionSelector.selectVersion(NearestVersionSelector.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.transformer.ConflictResolver.transformGraph(ConflictResolver.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
```

Given the stack trace, it looks like I have a circular dependency but I'm having trouble finding it. When I try to run `mvn dependency:tree` I get the same error.

I have also tried increasing the memory to 8192M but that just gives me a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error instead.

Any insight or ideas?

Comment: Did you try to restart the machine and then try running it ...just checking thats all

Comment: I would also assume a circular dependency as "GC overhead limit exceeded" tends to be a result of GC spending a lot of process time and not recovering much heap space.

You should try to work with a smaller set of dependencies and build your way up to identify which one is causing you issues.

Comment: can you build your project without eclipse? from command line. mvn install

Comment: First build on plain command line and which version of Maven are you using ?

Comment: We do build on the command line, I'm guessing that maven is using an eclipse library. We're using Maven 3.2.2.

Comment: @DaveM First Maven does not use a eclipse library ...furthermore why using such an older version of Maven and how many modules does your project have? Is this a multi module build? And how many dependencies does your project have?